# Using JSON Web Token (JWT) for both Authentication and Authorization

Tags: api, security, jwt

I have a serverless web app using AWS lambda functions. For JSON Web Token(JWT), you can specify the payload. Is it possible to specify payload like

```
user: example@any.com
authorization-level: admin
```

and use the resulting token to not only authorize users but also authenticate users? (EX. users technically do not even have to log in to access API and get personal information because token has user email, which we verify and return related payload)

Or is this a major security breach?

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to use JWT for both authentication and authorization, as long as you don't use NONE for signature algorithm. The signature guarantees that user has not tampered with the payload.